# Conflicting cross-version suffixes (sbt, Scala-STM, Play-JSON)

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

I am using a JSON extension which relies on Mandubian's play-json 2.2-SNAPSHOT. Everything worked fine until now I have a project based on Scala-STM. sbt reports the following problem:

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes 
        in {file:folder}project:
[error]    org.scala-stm:scala-stm _2.10, _2.10.0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: 
  org.scala-stm:scala-stm
```

Is there any chance to dig deeper into where these two "conflicting" versions come from? I am quite surprised that play-json should be depending on scala-stm?!

Furthermore, is there a way to convince sbt to shut the ... up. Because obviously 2.10 and 2.10.0 are equivalent versions.

---

**EDIT**: This seems to be an sbt 0.13 bug (and probably has nothing to do with Play-JSON), because if I revert to 0.12.4, the project successfully updates and builds. I am still interested in a work around for sbt 0.13.

Comment: Rather than use Mandubian's play-json SNAPSHOT, why not just add this dependency - `"play % "play_2.10" % "2.1.0"` per my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436069/adding-play-json-library-to-sbt

Comment: I am not sure it is a bug. I saw this problem too after upgrading, but then discovered that there were indeed two different versions of a library being used. It might be useful to turn it down to a warning I guess.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get around this by removing scala-stm with exclude

```
 "dependencyGroupId" %% "dependencyArtifactId" % "dependencyVersion" exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0")
```

Do not forget to do `sbt clean`.

Comment: Where do I add this in my `play` app? I presume `Build.scala`, but where inside of it?

Comment: `Build.scala` for a newly created project (Play 2.1.x, as 2.2 does not use Build.scala anymore) contains variable `val appDependencies` that contains a `Seq` with dependencies. Right inside of it.

Comment: @kompot, Play 2.2 and 2.3 can be used with either `build.sbt` or `Build.scala`.

Comment: What exactly does `exclude` do, it seems to be a catch all solution to when sbt is being a moron.  Surely there has to be some consequences?

Comment: exclude is described in http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html

Answer (score 2):

Updated Play2 2.2 - downgrading to SBT from 0.13.0 -> 0.12.4 didn't work with me, but excluding using exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0") on ALL app-specific dependencies I had worked fine -- anyway -- none of my dependencies shouldn't have anything to do with scala-stm.

Comment: So are you saying you had the same issue with Play 2.2?

Comment: Exactly. Problem occured when I was switching from Play2 2.1 to 2.2, before that all was fine with 0.12.4 and Play2 2.1

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to see all libraries being pulled in to your SBT project, you can use the [SBT dependency graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin.

Using this, you can see why scala-stm is being pulled in, and also check for other conflicting scala 2.10 and 2.11 dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I have this plugin now globally installed and use it a lot. A good recommendation.

Comment: that would be nice. but this plugin didnt work for me: "cannot resolve symbol virtual" in the line `net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings
`

Comment: @jsky That line should be in /build.sbt instead of /project/build.sbt.  Is that the case in your build?  Or use the alternative approach mentioned here: https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph#how-to-use