# How can I solve conflicting cross version suffixes in SBT?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, dependency-management

I have a Play project that uses a library that has recently been ported to Scala 2.11.1.

I have also updated Play to Scala 2.11.1.

When I try to run the project, I get:

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/...}:
[error]    org.scalaz:scalaz-core _2.11, _2.10
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scalaz:scalaz-core
```

I tried to detect which is the library that uses scalaz-core-2.10 using sbt-dependency-graph plugin. However, in the dependency graph tree, there is only one appearance of scalaz-core:

```
info]   | +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.11:7.0.6
```

So I am not sure which is the library that uses scalaz-core_2.10...How can I detect it?

I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242450/conflicting-cross-version-suffixes-sbt-scala-stm-play-json) that once I detect it, I could exclude it, but my problem is how to detect which is dependency that I have to exclude.

Comment: I recently had the same problem with Akka, it turned out I had put % instead of %% in the Spray dependency. Fixing that fixed the problem. I would check my build.sbt and check that all Scala libraries have %%

Comment: Does `last *:update` say something useful? Maybe you can share a library name, unless it's your private library.

Answer (score 7):

Under `target/resolution-cache/reports/` are Ivy's resolution report for each configuration.
Look for `*-compile.xml` and `*-test.xml` and see if you have

```
<module organisation="org.scalaz" name="scalaz-core_2.10">
   ....
</module>
```

This should tell you the `caller` of the module.